# Is normal order evaluation (call by name) further divided into call by value, call by reference, call by sharing, etc?

Tags: functional-programming, parameter-passing, programming-languages, lazy-evaluation, callbyname

Consider different ways of evaluating a procedure call and its arguments.
*Essentials of Programming Languages* says

> All the parameter-passing mechanisms (natural parameter passing, call by value, call by reference) we have discussed so far are eager:
>   they always ﬁnd a value for each operand. We now turn to a very different
>   form of parameter passing, called lazy evaluation.

What I understand about it is that:

- In applicative order evaluation (eager evaluation), we distinguish between call by value, call by reference, call by sharing, etc.
- In normal order evaluation (lazy evaluation, call by name), is there still similar distinction  between call by value, call by reference, call by sharing, etc?

Comment: if there's no value yet, there's nothing *to* reference, *or* share, *or* copy around. so, if I had to guess, no. But what does the book say? :) the book is peculiar, it builds its own theories, its own array of languages; if the authors wanted to arrange for a value to be referenced or shared or copied *after* it was calculated, they probably *could* define such a variation, who knows.

Comment: the usual distinction in the case of deferred (non-strict, ...) evaluation is whether the result is non-memoized (aka "call-by-name", which re-evaluates the expression to produce its value each time that value is needed) or indeed is memoized (aka "lazy" or "call-by-need" which evaluates the expression no more than once).